# Same actionhandler, multiple buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using JFrame to create an application and I want to know how it's possible to set the same actionhandler to different buttons. In my application I got 8 buttons and once you click on them, they should all disappear. This ''disappearing thing'' happens for each button, but after that each button does something different. So I want to save some lines by doing this, but I don't know how.

This is the code to explain what I mean:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class StackOverflowExample {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    StackOverflowExample window = new StackOverflowExample();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public StackOverflowExample() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");
        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                initialize2();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(75, 51, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btnNewButton.setVisible(false);
                btnNewButton_1.setVisible(false);
                btnNewButton_2.setVisible(false);
                btnNewButton_3.setVisible(false);
                initialize2();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(75, 85, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);


        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btnNewButton.setVisible(false);
                btnNewButton_1.setVisible(false);
                btnNewButton_2.setVisible(false);
                btnNewButton_3.setVisible(false);
                initialize2();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(75, 119, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);


        btnNewButton_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btnNewButton.setVisible(false);
                btnNewButton_1.setVisible(false);
                btnNewButton_2.setVisible(false);
                btnNewButton_3.setVisible(false);
                initialize2();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_3.setBounds(75, 153, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_3);
    }
    private void initialize2(){

        /*here I'll put the code for my new frame.
          I'll make like some more buttons and a textfield. 
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: `"This is the code to explain what I mean:..."` -- Sorry, but I'm still confused. What exactly are you trying to do? What is this code doing that it shouldn't be doing? What is it not doing that it should be doing?

Comment: Just add the same `ActionListener` to all buttons. Either assign your anonymous listener to a variable and call `addActionListener` of each button with this variable or create a concreate `ActionListener` class or let your class inherit from `ActionListener`.

Comment: Also, as an aside, your code contains many Swing newbie problems, including use of null layout with `setBounds(...)`, mention of use of multiple JFrames, both something that should be avoided. It also looks like you really want to use a CardLayout, rather than setting multiple components invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to make all components disappear and be replaced by a different "view", then the easiest way to do this is to use a CardLayout, and then call this object's `show(...)` method to show the view of choice when a button has been pushed, as demonstrated below. Note that each button gets its own `ButtonAction` object, one that extends AbstractAction. This is kind of like an ActionListener "on steroids" in that it has an `actionPerformed(...)` method that is called when the button is pressed, just the same as an ActionListener, but here we also set the button's text, we can set its mnemonic and/or icon if need be, and we can share Actions with other button like objects such as JMenuItems.

Also note that I strive to avoid `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)` at all costs. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SeveralButtons extends JPanel {
   // preferred size dimensions
   private static final int PREF_W = 450;
   private static final int PREF_H = 300;

   // number of buttons displayed
   private static final int BUTTON_COUNT = 4;
   public static final String BLANK_PANEL = "blank";
   public static final String MAIN_PANEL = "main panel";
   private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

   public SeveralButtons() {
      // create JPanel to hold our buttons. use a grid layout with 1 column
      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
      for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_COUNT; i++) {
          // create a new JButton and give it a an Action
         JButton button = new JButton(new ButtonAction(i));
         // add it to the buttonPanel
         buttonPanel.add(button);
      }

      // main JPanel to hold the buttonPanel
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
      mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);

      // set this class's layout
      setLayout(cardLayout);
      add(mainPanel, MAIN_PANEL); // add mainPanel
      add(new JPanel(), BLANK_PANEL);  // add a blank JPanel
   }

   @Override // so JPanel will be at least our desired size
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return superSz;
      }
      int prefW = Math.max(superSz.width, PREF_W);
      int prefH = Math.max(superSz.height, PREF_H);
      return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
   }

   // our AbstractAction class, an ActionListener "on steroids"
   private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      private int value;

      public ButtonAction(int i) {
         String name = "Button " + i;
         putValue(NAME, name);
         this.value = i;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // TODO: do some number specific action based on value
         // For a trivial example:
         String message = "Button pressed: " + value;
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) e.getSource(), message);

         // swap view to a blank view
         cardLayout.show(SeveralButtons.this, BLANK_PANEL);
      }
   }

   // create and display GUI in a thread-safe manner
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SeveralButtons mainPanel = new SeveralButtons();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SeveralButtons");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: You're a god. You explained this so well. When I reach 15 reputation, I'll be sure to thumb up your comment. :)

Comment: And if I want to give each button a different name, I can't use a nice for loop, can I?

Comment: I'm sorry to be bothering you again, but I tried to make a String array under the the method 'ButtonAction', but I got an error. This is the code I used:        String[] ButtonName = {"Chances Simples", "Douzaines", "Colonne", "Transversale simple", "Carré", "Transversale pleine", "Cheval", "Plein"};
        String name = ButtonName[i];
        putValue(NAME, name);
        this.value = i; @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1):

You should first create an actionlistener:

```
CustomActionListener actionListener = new CustomActionListener();
```

then add the actionListener to every button like:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

then create an inner class called CustomActionListener like this:

```
public class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
        //Code you want to perform when a button is pressed.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not really necessary in my opinion.